# How to get fragment from the view for Google Map v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I have my android application which was using `Google Map API v1 key` and it was working fine. Now I need to give my code to my professor and show him the working demo from scratch on a new desktop machine. So that means, now I cannot use `Google Map API v1 key` anymore so that is the reason I needed to make some changes in the code that I have for `Google Map API key v1` so that it can be used with `Google Map API v2 key`.

I am trying to show google map on `top half of the android screen` and `in my bottom half, I am trying to show the list view`.

Below is the code which works fine with `Google Map API v1 key` and now I need to make changes in the below code to make it work with `Google Map API v2 key` meaning I need to show Google Map on top half of the android screen.

```
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
user_id = bundle.getString("USERID");

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
scrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_with_list_menu, null);

setContentView(scrollView);

menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_menu, null);
app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_app, null);

ViewGroup tabBar = (ViewGroup) app.findViewById(R.id.tabBar);

initViewMembers(app); // I need to modify something in this method only

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

initMyLocationOverview();
registerLocationListener();

Button button1 = (Button) menu.findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) menu.findViewById(R.id.button2);

useLastKnownLocation(locationManager);

final View[] children = new View[] { menu, app };

// Scroll to app (view[1]) when layout finished.
int scrollToViewIdx = 1;
scrollView.initViews(children, scrollToViewIdx,
    new SizeCallbackForMenu(btnSlide));
}
```

This is the method I am supposed to modify. How can I modify the below method so that it will work with Google Map V2

```
/**
 * Initialize the map with default settings
 *
 */
private void initViewMembers(View app2) {

mapView = (MapView) app2.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

//map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

listView = (ListView) app2.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapController = mapView.getController();
mapController.setZoom(14);
mapView.setStreetView(true);

}
```

If you see in my above `initViewMembers method` I am using app2 view to get the mapView id and then use it in another place. If I am going to use `Google Map API v2 key` then I need to use `MapFragment` as mentioned in my next line which I have commented out. Now I am wondering how can I get the `map id` from the `app2 view` if I am using `Google Map API key v2`

So my question is how to get the MapFragment thing from the view?

Below is my `horz_scroll_app xml file` which has fragment for `Google Map v2`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_margin="2px"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2px" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/BtnSlide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0px"
            android:padding="0px"
            android:src="@drawable/button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:apiKey="0s_fADEBtq0-j_teQ1j-yaoDAivoHHtwN81rJ-g"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:state_enabled="true" />
    -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />


    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I cannot do something like this in my above initViewMembers method-

`map = ((MapFragment) app2.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

I am looking for something similar.

Comment: "If I am going to use Google Map API v2 key then I need to use MapFragment" -- no. Maps V2 has its own `MapView` widget, which you are welcome to use directly, instead of via `MapFragment`.

Comment: Can you show me an example that will work with my above scenario of that as it looks like Google Map API v2 is very confusing. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this in your xml

```
<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

This is how you can get the object reference

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

1) you need to import google-play-services_lib to your workspace.
2) add android-support-v4.jar
3) in you developer console activate android google maps v2 and get the api key.
4) add follwing permissions to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="YOURPACKAGE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="YOURPACKAGE.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I did like this..


public class CustomSupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup view,
            Bundle savedInstance) {
        View layout = super.onCreateView(inflater, view, savedInstance);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.transparent));
        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        map=getMap();   

        return layout;
    }

    /*public static CustomSupportMapFragment newInstance(GoogleMapOptions op) {

        CustomSupportMapFragment frag = new CustomSupportMapFragment();

        return frag;
    }
*/
    public GoogleMap getMapInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return map;
    }

}


xml..


  <fragment
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="300dp"
     class="com.maps.utils.CustomSupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: I know this thing already. But he want to see from the scratch in proper way so that if any other students are going to work on the same project then he should be able to explain them. So installing old apk is not the solution.

Comment: I was following that link only. You are not reading my question properly I guess. What I am saying is that, in my XML file I was using MapView for Google Map v1 and it was working fine. Now I commented out `MapView` with fragment for `Google Map V2` so that means, I need to modify my initviewmember method as well to have that change which I am not sure how to do that. As from a view app2, I don't know how to get `MapFragment`

Comment: you are showing me an example how to use google map v2 in android. But not the solution that I am looking for. I will still say, if you can read my question again, then you will get much better clarity what I am asking for.

Comment: Can I do it like this in my initViewMembers method? `map = ((MapFragment) app2.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();` I guess no right?

Comment: i think u need to pass Scrollview to your initViewMembers() method  like initViewMembers(scrollview)...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30295/discussion-between-techgeeky-and-msn)